# using sed to move dynamic string from one file and appending to second file

Tags: string, sed, append, move

i'm trying to move a dynamic string from a file and append it to the second file with sed.

what I have tried so far:

```
sed -i -e '/To300/{w /home/test/test1.txt' -e 'd}' /home/test/test2.txt
```

where XXXXTo300 is the string I want to move. Its moving the string to the second file, but when the next string is moved, its overwriting the existing strings in the second file.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this won't work, as `sed` overwrites the file each time you use the command. However, if you use `GNU sed`, you can work around this limitation by writing to `stdout` and redirecting:

```
sed -i -e '/To300/{w /dev/stdout' -e ';d }' oldfile >> newfile
```